# Template for UITableViewCell without nib files or storyboard

Tags: ios

I want to separate the code decide how the cell display from `UITableViewCell` class for reuse or switch template in runtime. Like this:

```
-(void)setTemplate:(MyTemplate *)template {
    [self.productName setStyleFrom:template.mainLabel];
    ....
}
```

And I don't want to use nib files or storyboard, code only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Prototype Cell if you Don't want to add Cell through .xib or class which is derived from UITableview cell

Click the link for Prototype cell  http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Thank you, but I made a mistake in my question, I meant not using storyboard and nib files, code only.